# Issue with getting the first matching item and its index position from a regex matching a string ( javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I've written a regex that matches all the function names in a string

```
Regex :- /([a-zA-Z ]*(?=\())/g
String:- (( MAX(1,2,3,4), min(1,2,3), max(3,4,5)))
```

Above regex matches all the function names by checking for a a bunch of words followed by "(". In this case the matches are **MAX**, **MIN**, **MAX** ( apart from some empty strings which I am filtering using match.filter(String). )

In one of my conditions I only need the "FIRST" Matching function along with its START and STOP index.
So, I wrote the following function to get it.

```
var re = /([a-zA-Z ]*(?=\())/g;    
var str = "max(1,2), min(1,2)";

while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
  // Pick the first matching index from here ? 
}
```

But this is going into an infinte loop and it's not giving the desired output ( I am sure something is wrong with the function above, but not quite sure what ).

```
Example string2 = (((( max(34234,234234,344) min(1,2,3)))))*23 + max(23434, 234234,234234)))  - I only need the first matching function "max" from here along with it's start and stop index's.
```

Comment: Consider using a parser here instead of regex.

Comment: For what do you need the index of the text inside the parenthesis? If you simply want to extract the function name and the function parameters you can use this regex: `/([a-zA-Z]+) *\(([^\)]*)\)/g`

Comment: @PeterThoeny I was only looking to extract the function names. I need not have the parameter list. ( the output should be just the function name - max, min  and their starting char positions and ending positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution expects the pattern you provided (specifically spaces before and after function.)

The `.match()` method provides an `index` for the start position and use the `.length` property of the string to get the end position:

```js
let string = '(((( max(34234,234234,344) min(1,2,3)))))*23 + max(23434, 234234,234234)))';
let result = '';
while (result != null) {
  result = string.match(/\w+(?=\()/);
  if (result != null) {
    console.log('Found: ' + result, 'Start: ' + result.index, 'End: ' + parseInt(result[0].length + result.index));
  }
  string = string.split(result)[1];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I was more of looking at extracting on the function names - max, min and their starting and ending positions. I don't need to match the parameters.

Comment: Answer is edited. Please verify if that is what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the index to get the function name and the parameters? If so, you do no need the index, and can get the function name and parameters directly using this regex: `/([a-zA-Z]+) *\(([^\)]*)\)/g`:

```js
const testCases = [
  'max(1,2), min(1,2)',
  '(( MAX(1,2,3,4), min (1,2,3), max(3,4,5)))'
];
let regex = /([a-zA-Z]+) *\(([^\)]*)\)/g;
let matches = testCases.forEach(str => {
  console.log('input: ' + str);
  let match = regex.exec(str);
  while(match) {
    console.log('- name: ' + match[1] + ', params: ' + match[2]);
    match = regex.exec(str);
  }
});
```

Output:

```
input: max(1,2), min(1,2)
- name: max, params: 1,2
- name: min, params: 1,2
input: (( MAX(1,2,3,4), min (1,2,3), max(3,4,5)))
- name: MAX, params: 1,2,3,4
- name: min, params: 1,2,3
- name: max, params: 3,4,5
```

This example extracts all function name & parameter pairs. Remove the while if you are only interested in the first one:

```
    let matches = testCases.forEach(str => {
      console.log('input: ' + str);
      let match = regex.exec(str);
      console.log('- name: ' + match[1] + ', params: ' + match[2]);
    });
```

Explanation of regex:

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - capture group 1: function name is 1+ alpha
- `*` - optional space
- `\(` - opening parenthesis
- `([^\)]*)` - capture group 2: everything up to just before the closing parenthesis
- `\)` - closing parenthesis

Note that I changed your regex from `([a-zA-Z ]*)` to `([a-zA-Z]+) *` to avoid false positives like `MA X (1,2)`.

Comment: sorry couldn't respond to you sooner. As I pointed out in my question, I am also looking for the index ( start and stop ) positions of the function names that matched. Your solution just gives me all the functions and parameters. I can surely upvote your answer but not sure if I can accept it as a solution . If you care to modify the solution to fit to the asked question, I would surely accept it.  Thanks for the detailed explanation of the regex. P.S. I figured out a different way using a parser, but nevertheless the solution would be helpful for people landing here for indexs